# Trying to input data from a txt file in a list, then make a list, then assign values to the lines

Tags: python, string, list, append

```
allt = []
with open('towers1.txt','r') as f:   
    towers = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]
    for i in towers:
        allt.append(i.split('\t'))
    print allt [0]
```

now i need help, im inputting this text

```
mw91 42.927 -72.84 2.8
yu9x 42.615 -72.58 2.3
HB90 42.382 -72.679 2.4
```

and when i output im getting

```
['mw91 42.927 -72.84 2.8']
```

where in my code and what functions can i use to define the 1st 2nd 3rd and 4th values in this list and all the ones below that will output, im trying

```
allt[0][2] or 
allt[i][2]
```

but that dosent give me -72.84, its an error, then other times it goes list has no attribute split

update, maybe i need to use enumerate?? i need to make sure though the middle 2 values im imputing though can be used and numbers and not strings because im subtracting them with math

Comment: instead of allt.append(i.split('\t')) try allt.append(i.split(' '))

Comment: nope the whole thing goes crazy, i get 20 lines of output starting from the left, the 19 in the next column, then 18 and so on till the far right column has 1 row @smac89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure those are tabs? You can specify no argument for split and it automatically splits on whitespace (which means you won't have to strip newlines beforehand either). I copied your sample into a file and got it to work like this:

```
allt = []
with open('towers1.txt','r') as f:   
   for line in f:
        allt.append(line.split())

>>>print allt[0]
['mw91', '42.927', '-72.84', '2.8']
>>>print allt[0][1]
'42.927'
```

Footnote: if you get rid of your first list comprehension, you're only iterating the file once, which is less wasteful.

---

Just saw that you want help converting the float values as well. Assuming that `line.split()` splits up the data correctly, something like the following should probably work:

```
allt = []
with open('towers1.txt','r') as f:   
   for line in f:
         first, *_else = line.split() #Python3
         data = [first]
         float_nums = [float(x) for x in _else]
         data.extend(float_nums)
         allt.append(data)

>>>print allt[0]
['mw91', 42.927, -72.84, 2.8]
```

For Python2, substitute the `first, *_else = line.split()` with the following:

```
first, _else = line.split()[0], line.split()[1:]
```

---

Finally (in response to comments below), if you want a list of a certain set of values, you're going to have to iterate again and this is where list comprehensions can be useful. If you want the `[2]` index value for each element in `allt`, you'll have to do something like this:

```
 >>> some_items = [item[2] for item in allt]
 >>> some_items
 [-72.84, -72.58, -72.679]
```

Comment: the only problem i have is, when i type say print allt[2] i want it to print use in the next line of code all the 20 lines of text i have in the file in the 3rd spot. ie. above -72.84 -72.58 then -72.679 all again

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but it sounds like you want to print a particular column for each line of values (and this is how it looks based on requested input). If so, you're always going to have to loop. (I'll put an example above).

Comment: thanks also, (first, *_else) is an error, line 4 in your code, on my comp. it says around the *

Comment: Ah, that's a Python3 thing I didn't think about. You can try to use the following instead:  `first, _else = line.split()[0], line.split()[1:]`

Comment: so if i get item1 and item2 in a set and input them into a function and i get values returned, will the item1 and item2 know which item0 they came from??

Comment: That's a bit too vague for me to interpret. It sounds like you want to keep using them indexed (as a 2d array, or lists within lists) or it sounds like you'll need some kind of structure, such as a dictionary. You might want to start a new question with the new problem you're having (with code samples, sample input and output). It's really tough to debug in comments and answers just get longer and longer (and inutile as a result).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34805/discussion-between-user2605035-and-erewok)

Answer (score 0):

[] implies a list.

'' implies a string.

allt = ['mw91 42.927 -72.84 2.8']

allt is a list that contains a string:

allt[0]  --> 'mw91 42.927 -72.84 2.8'

allt[0][2]  -->  '9'

allt.split()  -->  ['mw91', '42.927', '-72.84', '2.8']

allt.split()[2] -->  '-72.84'  #This is still a string.

float(allt.split()[2]) --> -72.84  #This is now a float.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should also work

```
with open('towers.txt', 'r') as f:
    allt = map(str.split, f)
```

And if you need the values after the first one to be floats...

```
with open('towers.txt', 'r') as f:
    allt = [line[:1] + map(float, line[1:]) for line in map(str.split, f)]
```